# Using Google Geocode results outside of Vue.js function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am learning Vue.js and delving into google maps and geocoding. I am translating a location into lat/long results. I am using code that successfully returns the desired result from Google, but I am unable to access the variables outside of the if statement.I am bit stumped and could use some help for me to learn.

```
        var geocoder = new window.google.maps.Geocoder();
                var address = "Dublin";
               geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                if (status == window.google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                  var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                  var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                  console.log(latitude) //returns correct data
                  console.log(longitude) //returns correct data
                  this.me = longitude
                          } 
                  }); 
                console.log(this.me) //returns nothing!!
 console.log(longitude) //returns nothing!!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is mainly about `this`. Changing `function` as an arrow function will help to change the this correctly.

```
var geocoder = new window.google.maps.Geocoder();
                var address = "Dublin";
               geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, (results, status) => {
                if (status == window.google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                  var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                  var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                  console.log(latitude) //returns correct data
                  console.log(longitude) //returns correct data
                  this.me = longitude
                          } 
                  }); 
                console.log(this.me) //returns nothing!!
 console.log(longitude) //returns nothing!!
```

I did not try to run the code, as this is part of the code, but it should work.

Try reading this for details. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Thanks for the response and answer, the link is really useful. Just when I start to think I'm getting my head around JS and VUE, I get stuck on something relatively straightforward. Appreciate the help.

Comment: You are welcome, this is actually not an issue on Vue, but a misconception of Javascript. Hope the info helps you.